# Storing "variables" in a list and then insert them into database foreach other list column_values

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to do something like this, the values for method_list and currency_list would come from a form. An insert needs to occur for each method for as many times as there are currencies aka if there are 3 currecies then for VISA method it has to insert a row 3 times and then for MASTER method 3 times. Configuration exists for each method.

```
declare
  method_list sys.odcivarchar2list;
  currency_list sys.odcivarchar2list;
begin
  method_list := sys.odcivarchar2list( 
    (method:='VISA' , deposit:=1), 
    (method:='MASTER' , deposit:=0)
  );
  currency_list := sys.odcivarchar2list('EUR','USD','GBP');
  INSERT INTO table (method, currency, deposit, confcode)
  SELECT m.method, c.column_value, m.deposot, conf.code
  FROM method_list m, currency_list c, conf
  WHERE conf.method = m.method
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly select from the arrays by putting `table()` around them in the `from` clause:

```
  1  declare
  2    method_list sys.odcivarchar2list;
  3    currency_list sys.odcivarchar2list;
  4  begin
  5    method_list := sys.odcivarchar2list(
  6      'VISA',
  7      'MASTER'
  8    );
  9    currency_list := sys.odcivarchar2list('EUR','USD','GBP');
 10    for r in (
 11    SELECT m.column_value m_value, c.column_value c_value
 12    FROM table(method_list) m, table(currency_list) c
 13    )
 14    loop
 15       dbms_output.put_line (r.m_value || ' ' || r.c_value);
 16    end loop;
 17* end;
SQL> /
VISA EUR
VISA USD
VISA GBP
MASTER EUR
MASTER USD
MASTER GBP

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

However, you cannot use the sort of pseudo-JSON syntax you did with method_list (though in 12c real JSON [is supported in PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6246)).

But you could create your own types like:

```
create type method_obj_t is object (method varchar2(10), deposit integer);

create type method_tab_t is table of method_obj_t;
```

Then you could select from those using `table()`:

```
declare
  method_list method_tab_t;
  currency_list sys.odcivarchar2list;
begin
  method_list := method_tab_t(
    method_obj_t('VISA',1),
    method_obj_t('MASTER',0)
  );
  currency_list := sys.odcivarchar2list('EUR','USD','GBP');
  for r in (
  SELECT m.method, m.deposit, c.column_value c_value
  FROM table(method_list) m, table(currency_list) c
  )
  loop
     dbms_output.put_line (r.method || ' ' || r.deposit || ' ' || r.c_value);
  end loop;
end;
```